# Trying to find out the meaning of my birthmark

Tags: symbolism

I have a birth mark on the bottom of my right foot. It is a crescent moon reddish in color... it faces the same way a C would. I'm just curious if it has a significant meaning to it because I've always felt a strong connection to the moon and things like crystals and all that cool type of stuff.. !

[photo of the foot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vA0CG.jpg)

Comment: ideally a smaller photo of the foot with a detail of the mark would be better.  That massive of your foot is just too much!

Answer (score -1):

Informally, I'd say the crescent can definite be taken as a lunar symbol, reinforcing your connection to the moon.

Regarding the letter C in relation to quartz crystals, this is much shakier because "crystal" is an English word, and has different forms in other languages: *kristall* is German for crystal; in Catalan it's *vidre*; in Chinese it's 水晶 (*Shuǐjīng*).  You can see the problem.

---

There is a nice semi-mythical parallel using letters, in the sense that Shakespeare can be considered a myth-maker.  (Mythology defined here from a strictly narrative, as opposed to religious, perspective:)

> Richard plots to have his brother Clarence, who stands before him in the line of succession, executed over a prophecy that "G of King Edward's heirs the murderer shall be". Richard leads the king to interpret this as referring to **G**eorge of Clarence, without realizing it actually refers to Richard of **G**loucester.

*(PS--don't trust wiki entirely.  Always best to read or see the play.  George of Clarence isn't drowned in a any old wine, but a "butt of [malmsey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malvasia)";)*